# Write length function for list with statically typed length

Tags: haskell, types

Given a list with a statically typed length (taking [this](http://jeltsch.wordpress.com/2012/04/30/dependently-typed-programming-and-theorem-proving-in-haskell/) as an example):

```
data Zero

data Succ nat

data List el len where
    Nil  ::                      List el Zero
    Cons :: el -> List el len -> List el (Succ len)
```

is it possible to write a length function that calculates the length using the static typing rather than the usual recursion?

My efforts thus far have led me to the conclusion that it is not possible, as it would require "unlifting" the type information in order to recur on it:

```
class HasLength a where
    length :: a -> Natural

instance HasLength (List el Zero) where
    length _ = 0

instance HasLength (List el (Succ len)) where
    length _ = 1 + *how to recur on type of len*
```

However, I am only just beginning to learn about all the magic possible with types, so I know that my not being able to conceive of a solution does not imply the absence of one.

**update**

Since length returns Natural, I incorrectly wrote `length _ = 1 + ...`. The correct instance (using the answer given below) is

```
instance HasLength (List el len) => HasLength (List el (Succ len)) where
    length _ = succ $ length (undefined :: List el len)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For example like this:

```
instance HasLength (List el len) => HasLength (List el (Succ len)) where
    length _ = 1 + length (undefined :: List el len)
```

Note: this requires `ScopedTypeVariables` extension.

Answer (score 1):

This will be much easier if you use the `DataKinds` extension, which will allow you to 'promote' `Natural` to a kind, which makes the (promoted) types `Zero` and `Succ n` more tractable and eliminates nonsense like `Succ Char`. There are several ways of going about it, but sticking close to your text:

```
{-#LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, StandaloneDeriving  #-}
data Natural = Zero | Succ Natural deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)

data List el len  where
    Nil  ::                      List el Zero 
    Cons :: el -> List el len -> List el (Succ len) 

deriving instance Show el => Show (List el len)

class HasLength f where len ::  f n -> Natural

instance HasLength (List el) where
    len Nil = Zero
    len (Cons _ xs) = Succ (len xs)
```

(I also used `StandaloneDeriving`, which is needed to automatically derive `Show` in such cases.)

Comment: Thanks applicative, you're right; this is a lot cleaner. However, I get the following when I try to run it:
 
    `Kind mis-match
    The first argument of HasLength should have kind * -> *,
    but List el has kind Natural -> *
    In the instance declaration for HasLength (List el)`
 
 and I'm afraid I don't know the appropriate fix for this. It seems specifying that the argument to HasLength should have kind `Natural -> *` would make it unnecessarily specific, but I'm not sure. Any advice? :)

Comment: Hm, It may be ghc versions -- these things are new since ghc-7.4.  Or maybe I'm missing something.  You can add a kind signature to `HasLength` that specializes it. But this -- with an instance for both your length-indexed Lists, and regular haskell lists, runs fine for me with either  ghc-7.4 or ghc-7.6  http://hpaste.org/78395

Comment: Aha, your hpaste cleared it up. I was lacking the PolyKinds pragma. Thanks a lot!